# how to Replace masked out cloud areas with another satellite image?

Tags: masking, sentinel-snap

I have a Sentinel 2 image which has heavy cloud cover. I would like to mask out the clouds, and replace these areas with a Landsat 8 image.

(1) How do I mask out cloud?

(2) how to I replace the cloud areas with the Landsat 8 image?

I am using SNAP software.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the software, a generic method :

- You need to classify clouds into a binary mask (0 - no cloud/1 - clouds)
- You use your mask as a conditional raster where :

  - if 0 then keep one source of Data (Sentinel 2)
  - if 1 (or else) then keep another source of data (Landsat 8)

EDIT : I just saw you use SNAP software. I don't know it but i leave my generic method in case it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As you specifically state that you are using the SNAP software I would have thought you would get a better response by posting on the [STEP forum](http://forum.step.esa.int/)?

Comment: I have posted this there aswell